# Complete path name to a file to include in a code

Tags: c++

How can I find a complete path to a file in my computer? I need it to include in my c++ project. I know I I have to change the / in the path. However, everytime I copy and paste the path the code does not seem to be able to find it. (the program has to read from the file).

Comment: have you tried `pwd` command inside the folder containing the file you want (assuming you are using linux)? After that you should know the complete path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, 
Right click file >> Go to Propeties >> Copy path next to Location: field >> add file name with extension to it
Ex:

[image: Example]

Here location is: G:\Python\MD5 Decryption using Bruteforce
add file name at last that is MD5.py in my case
So path is: "G:\Python\MD5 Decryption using BruteforceMD5.py"

While on linux:
use `readlink -f file.txt` command

Open terminal, go to directory containing that file and excecute above command (replacing file.txt with your file name) ..